# Why would one choose Iron Python instead of Boo?

Tags: .net, python, ironpython, boo

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [BOO Vs IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600539/boo-vs-ironpython)
>   [Boo vs. IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193862/boo-vs-ironpython)

Say you want to embed a scripting language into a .NET application.

Boo is modelled on Python syntax, but also includes type inference, and just in general seems to be a better, more modern language to embed as a scripting language.

Why, then, is there so much fuss about Iron Python?

*LATER*
As was pointed out, this question is an exact duplicate of: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193862/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600539)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193862/boo-vs-ironpython

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600539

Comment: Sorry did not see the duplicate. Will close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IronPython is directly developed and supported by Microsoft (under the awesome technical lead of Jim Hugunin!), AND has an insanely great book about it ("IronPython in Action", which I'm biased about but nevertheless evangelize shamelessly). Apart from that, Boo appears to be a great contender, and I'd love to try it out (were I ever to use .NET in earnest rather than as a for-fun endeavor -- as my professional development these days targets Linux and Mac, not Windows, that doesn't seem a likely prospect).

If you're using .NET as your main development target, my recommendation is to pick a few small but not toy projects in your area of expertise and develop each of them in both Boo and IronPython (alternating which one goes first) -- after you're through a few, you'll KNOW what's right for you. That's how I ended up switching from Perl 4 to Python as my main language back in the '90s (rather than sticking with Perl 4, of which I was an expert and guru, or switching to then-brand-new Perl 5) -- a few "pilot projects" fully developed in each environment left me with no doubt about what was best for my own productivity.

Answer (score 2):

2 words: User Base.

I already know so many languages that I have to keep references handy so I can remember if it's "else if", "elsif" or "elif" in whatever I'm currently working in. Unless there's a compelling reason to use another language (more than just a few small differences) I'm going to stick with one I already know.

Comment: Isn't IronPython slower than Boo? As far as I know Boo is as fast as C# but I heard that IronPython is a little slower. Forget where I heard it though :/

Answer (score 0):

People like python, and they don't want anything else. Is there really anything else to this question?

Comment: was hoping for some insight on something that Python does that Boo doesn't, I guess